# R-reshaping with missing data

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataset(df) that looks something like this.

```
ID  Variable    Value
A   Height  4
A   Height  4.5
A   Height  5
B   Height  5
B   Height  5.2
B   Height  5.3
C   Height  5.1
C   Height  5.1
C   Height  5.25
A   Weight  110
A   Weight  112
A   Weight  120
B   Weight  111
B   Weight  110
C   Weight  120
C   Weight  114
C   Weight  115
```

Each variable  is listed 3 times except for "Weight" for B. I need to cast it to the following form.

```
ID  Height1 Height2 Height3 Weight1 Weight2 Weight3
A   4        4.5      5       110   112     120
B   5        5.2    5.3       111   110      .
C   5.1      5.1    5.25      120   114     115
```

Any ideas on how I could do that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @Floo0 tried a simple cast (df, id~variable) but that doesn't solve it. Thought about tagging 1, 2,3, each time a variable is repeated for each ID, but the problem was some variables are listed only twice. My dataset is really long and it is not possible to manually manipulate that.

Comment: how do you know which height and weight correspond after casting to columns `Height1`, `Height2`, etc?

Comment: @ beasterfied by the order in which it appears. if it the height that appeared first on the list, that would be Height1, second one would be height 2...and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the heights and weights are in order within `ID` already, the following will work.  I used dplyr to add in a variable to represent the sequence of height and weight within each `ID`.

```
require(dplyr)    
dat = dat %>% group_by(ID, Variable) %>% mutate(seq = 1:n())

require(reshape2)
datwide = dcast(dat, ID ~ Variable + seq, value.var = "Value", fill = ".")
names(datwide) = sub("_", "", names(datwide))
```

The `fill` argument is used for defining what you want to put in for the missing values.  I don't know how to remove the underscore from the names within `dcast`, but I've used `sub` in the past to replace them.

As @Beasterfield pointed out, it would be cleaner to simply add the numbers representing the sequence of heights and weights to the variable name.  Because I was using `Variable` as a grouping variable I couldn't modify it directly (this could be user error).  Instead I made `Variable2` to use in `dcast`.

```
dat = dat %>% group_by(ID, Variable) %>% mutate(Variable2 = paste0(Variable, 1:n()) )
datwide = dcast(dat, ID ~ Variable2, value.var = "Value", fill = ".")
```

Comment: if the column names have to be exactly in the same format as in the question, one could directly modify the `Variable`column by `mutate( Variable = paste0(Variable, 1:n()) )`.

Comment: @Beasterfields suggestion is good and it enables you to use `spread()` (from tidyr) like `dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Variable = paste(Variable, 1:n(), sep = ".")) %>% spread(Variable, Value)`

Comment: Good thinking @Beasterfield.  That's better than having to edit the names after.

Comment: I definitely have to dive deeper into `tidyr`. Its too elegant, to miss that.